# Grease Pencil (2.8) How to draw with custom line types (updated)

Tags: grease-pencil

Is it possible in Blender 2.8 to create (or maybe import from vector files or something like that) other types of strokes than the three proposed by default in the software (line, dots and boxes).

The idea would be to be able to draw with ready-made types of lines of different kinds (like those here https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZP4v.png)

If this is not possible, is it at least possible to draw lines with evenly spaced dots and boxes?

---

**Small update (I'm still trying to figure out how to do it)**

It is possible to create a texture and apply it to the line. So I tested by creating an image with a transparent background, drew a point on it and imported it into Grease Pencil in order to generate a dotted line.

But I still have many problems with it: the line is irregular, especially when I draw slowly or according to the stroke angle:

[image]

In addition, the pattern is often crushed. I discovered that this issue could be fixed using the "UV Factor" option. But as soon as I change the brush size, the problem comes back:

[image]

I'm looking for a way to draw a line that stays regular by adapting to the size of the brush, the angle of the stroke etc.

while doing some research, I came across this:  https://code.blender.org/2018/07/grease-pencil-status-update/     The "Drawing brushes with assigned Material" section seems to correspond to what I am looking for, but I don't know how to configure the feature to get a good result

Answer (score 0):

In Blender 3.0.0 you can use the [Dot Dash Modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/grease_pencil/modifiers/generate/dash.html) on a Grease Pencil object.

It works by toggling the visibility of points/segments along strokes, so you may need to subdivide your strokes to get enough points. Or dissolve some points to reduce the count if your points are too dense.

[image: Screenshot of Blender 3.0.0 showing a GreasePencil object in Edit mode with a Dot Dash modifier applied]